# While converting rotation matrix to angle-axis representation how to find axis of rotation when angle of rotation is Pi?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I have to convert a $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix into angle-axis representation.

Angle($\theta$) can be calculated using $tr (\mathbf{R}) = 1+2\cos{\theta}$ and vector $v$ corrresponding to the axis of rotation can be calculated using :

$v= {\dfrac {1}{2\sin(\theta)}}\begin{bmatrix}
r_{32}-r_{23} \\
r_{13}-r_{31} \\
r_{21} -r_{12} 
\end{bmatrix}$ where $r_{ij}$ are appropriate entries of $R$ matrix.

The above representation for $v$ works fine when $0$ $<$ $\theta$ < $\pi$, but what method has to be applied when $\theta$ comes out to be $\pi$/-$\pi$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I hope the edited version of the question is more clear  :)

Comment: Yes. It is much better now.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MYtR67WFBqjerUVwiIPPIhKn57gCe0g1)  

The above link has a representation for rotation matrix which can be used for finding the angle-axis form when **theta = pi** , but I can't find a way to use it

Comment: @MSD I'm curious, something unclear MSD in my answer?

Comment: @Widawensen Actually I was on a holiday..... I will try to implement it in the matlab function today :)

Comment: @MSD Impelementation is rather simple.  You need only to calculate $A=(R+I)/2$ and consider **non-zero** entries on the diagonal. Suppose $a_{11} = v_x^2 \neq 0$, then $ v_x=\pm\sqrt{a_{11}}$ ( two solutions) . Having $ v_x$ other components $v_y,v_z$ you have from $a_{21}=v_xv_y$  and  $a_{31}=v_xv_z$.

Comment: @Widawensen I have implemented this but it fails for certain cases. The mathematics is absoluetly clear....may be some other issue

Comment: v= ${\dfrac {1}{2\sin(\theta)}}\begin{bmatrix}
r_{32}-r_{23} \\
r_{13}-r_{31} \\
r_{21} -r_{12} 
\end{bmatrix}$

Is it OK ?
I am using this for the case of 0 < $\theta$ < $\pi$

Comment: @MSD What are the cases when the formula fails? The formula is good for sure, also your formula is good not only for $0<\theta<\pi$, but also for $-\pi<\theta<0$, it follows from Rodrigues formula and calculation $R-R^T $ ..  you probably calculate $\theta$ from $tr(R)=1+2\cos(\theta)$, note that you have from this equation two solutions $\pm$ for $\theta$ ..

Comment: @Widawensen  There must be some problem in the code, as its failing in the case $\theta$ = 108$\deg$
I'm expecting some silly mistake in the code......I'll update you once correctly done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Rodrigues formula for a rotation matrix $R$

$$R=I+\sin(\theta)S(v)+(1-\cos(\theta))S^2(v)$$

where $S(v)$ is  a skew-symmetric matrix corresponding to  the vector $v$

$$S(v)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -v_z & v_y  \\
v_z & 0 & -v_x \\
-v_y & v_x & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

You can check that relation $$S^2(v)=vv^T-I$$  holds ( $v$ has to be unit vector here)
and  for $$\theta=\pi$$
we have very useful relation
$$R=I+2(vv^T-I)$$ and consequently $$vv^T=\dfrac{1}{2}(R+I) $$

The matrix  $$vv^T=\begin{bmatrix}
v_x^2 &  v_y v_x& v_zv_x  \\
v_xv_y &  v_y^2& v_z v_y\\
 v_x v_z &  v_y v_z & v_z^2
\end{bmatrix}$$ allows  to calculate $$v = [ v_x \ \  v_y \ \ v_z]^T $$ 
directly from obtained entries of the matrix (two solutions $R(v,\pi)=R(-v,\pi))$.